# PHP function giving error in my system

Tags: php

I don't know why the code below giving an error on my laptop while not at my friend's.

```
<?php
    function myfunction() : int {
        return 10;
    }
    echo myfunction();
?>
```

**Error**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in (my location) on line 2.

If I remove the ": int" on line 2 everything is fine, but can someone explain why this code can't run on mine?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Return type declarations weren't added until version 7.

Comment: It seems you have a php version which is less than 7

Comment: You can check your php version as the php version might be below 7 which is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration). It is a PHP7+ only feature.

What might be a good idea as a work around, until you migrate to PHP7, is to do the following:

```
function myfunction() {
    return (int)10;
}

var_dump(myfunction());
```

That will convert the return to an integer.

---

It's worth noting, this won't throw any warnings if the return value cannot be resolved.
I.E. If you passed parameters and those parameters were letters in a string, for instance, you'd get `Warning: A non-numeric value encountered`. However, for now, I think the above solution will suffice.

I strongly recommend upgrading to the latest version of PHP, though.